# Identifying the equation of the surface containing all points that have a distance to the x-axis twice that to the yz-plane

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

The distance $D_{1}$ of an arbitrary point P(x, y, z) to the x-axis can be obtained using the right angled triangle formed by the coordinates of the point:
$$y^2 + z^2 = D^2\\
D_{1} = \sqrt{y^2+z^2}$$

The distance $D_{2}$ from P to the yz-plane, $x = 0$, is found by:

$$D_{2} = \frac{|ax + by + cz + d|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}} = \frac{|1x + 0y + 0z + 0|}{\sqrt{1^2}} = |x|$$

Equating the two distances:

$$D_{1} = D_{2}\\
\sqrt{y^2+z^2} = 2|x|$$

The resulting equation is in the form of an elliptic cone, its axis being the x-axis:

$$y^2 + z^2 = 4x^2$$

Have I correctly identified the surface that contains all points twice the distance to the x-axis as to the yz-plane? What other methods could be used to find this surface?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your working is correct but the surface is not an elliptic cone, rather a double right circular cone with vertex at $(0, 0, 0)$ and its axis along x-axis, one of them opening up to the left of yz-plane and one to the right of it -

$2x = \sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ and $2x = - \sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

For a given $x = x_0$, $y^2+z^2 = (2x_0)^2$ represents a circle of radius $2 |x_0|$ in plane $x = x_0$ centered at $(x_0, 0, 0)$.

The opening angle of the cone (the angle between axis of the cone and slant line) is $ \ \displaystyle \phi = \arctan (2) \approx 63.4^0$

Here is a 3D view of the surface and its projection in yz plane at a given x, which is a circle:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$y^2+z^2= r^2$$

$ r= x \cdot \tan \alpha = 2 x $ is a circular cone of semi-vertical angle $\alpha= \tan^{-1}2.$

The cone is swept out by rotation of $ y= 2x \text { or } z=2 x$  about the x-axis.